# PHP - Extend Wordpress Woocommerce Revenue Analytics with custom field

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

i'm familiar with wordpress plugin development and use of hook and filters. By the way i'm encountering a big lack of documentation about what i write on the title.
The need is to implement a new "total box" in Woocommerce Revenue Dashboard with a custom indicator that I want to calculate in a custom way.

The problem is that i found the filter "woocommerce_analytics_revenue_select_query" to manipulate the "standard" indicators, i can also add new custom data in the object returned by the ajax stats call, but the problem remain on how to add a Custom Box.

Here what i'm talking about speaking about "BOX WITH CUSTOM FIELD":

[image: Here what i'm talking about speaking about "BOX WITH CUSTOM FIELD"]

Going in the deep of ajax calls i found that those Boxes are defined in a Javascript that is under the /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocomerce-admin/dist/chunks/analytics-report-revenue.js but they are fixed (or maybe the files are auto-generated on plugin's installation/upgrade). So if i un-minify the file i found on line 935:

```
            var a = r(3),
            n = r(49),
            o = Object(n.applyFilters)("woocommerce_admin_revenue_report_charts", [{
                key: "gross_sales",
                label: Object(a.__)("Gross Sales", 'woocommerce'),
                order: "desc",
                orderby: "gross_sales",
                type: "currency"
            }, {
                key: "refunds",
                label: Object(a.__)("Returns", 'woocommerce'),
                order: "desc",
                orderby: "refunds",
                type: "currency"
            }, {
                key: "coupons",
                label: Object(a.__)("Coupons", 'woocommerce'),
                order: "desc",
                orderby: "coupons",
                type: "currency"
            }, {
                key: "net_revenue",
                label: Object(a.__)("Net Sales", 'woocommerce'),
                orderby: "net_revenue",
                type: "currency"
            }, {
                key: "taxes",
                label: Object(a.__)("Taxes", 'woocommerce'),
                order: "desc",
                orderby: "taxes",
                type: "currency"
            }, {
                key: "shipping",
                label: Object(a.__)("Shipping", 'woocommerce'),
                orderby: "shipping",
                type: "currency"
            }, {
                key: "total_sales",
                label: Object(a.__)("Total Sales", 'woocommerce'),
                order: "desc",
                orderby: "total_sales",
                type: "currency"
            } , **{ // added custom object
                key: "custom_indicator",
                label: Object(a.__)("Custom Computation", 'woocommerce'),
                order: "desc",
                orderby: "whatever",
                type: "currency"
            }**
```

Now, if I add another of these JSON Object i OBTAIN the the new BOX with the custom field on the dashboard, so it WORKS. The problem is that I have to work on a JS file in the STANDARD plugin, so i cannot upgrade it or re-install or i don't know if the file will be re-generated in the future by some feature. I'm looking for a "elegant way" to override/extend that file, maybe acting using some filters that allow to obtain the expected goal.

I already tried to use filters "written" in the js or that i found looking into the woocomerce code, but they are never fired during the upgrade process:  woocommerce_admin_revenue_report_charts
woocommerce_rest_report_revenue_stats_schema
woocommerce_admin_revenue_report_advanced_filters
woocommerce_admin_revenue_report_filters

Does anyone have some experience with that? I found nothing about it in the web.

The goal is to handle this custom field on a separate custom plugin that works with woocommerce without touching the standard.

Thank you